# Asynchronous bash script

Tags: bash, asynchronous

I've seen a few examples out there but not been able to work them to my situation.

I have a script that calls a long running command, but I want to periodically (say every 1s) get the status of that call. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl localhost:9200/my_index/_forcemerge?max_num_segments=2 &

while [ command is running ]; do
  curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/shards/my_index?v&h=index,shard,prirep,segments.count
  sleep 1
done

echo "finished!"
```

Is it possible to get the status of the child process in this way?

Edit: Clarifying what I'm actually doing. It's actually two curl commands to an Elasticsearch cluster. The long running command merges data segments together, the "status" command will get the current segment count.

Comment: You can only get the status of that long running command only after it completes! need more information for this, is the `command.sh` runs multiple commands on the background or just one command only? and how much time it takes on a average for it to complete

Comment: Yes this is possible, but you are not clear an what you mean by the status? Are you talking about completion? Which part of your examples is the one that you need help with? The `while [ command is running ]` part of the `/script/that/gets/status.sh` part?

Comment: Ok, so to clarify, the long running command is a curl command. Normally takes about 10 minutes. The status, is the status of the merge called by the curl command (it'll actually be another curl command).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the safest way of doing this is to save the process ID of the child process and then periodically check to see if this is still running:

```
#!/bin/bash

mycommand &
child_pid=$!

while kill -0 $child_pid >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    echo "Child process is still running"
    sleep 1
done

echo "Child process has finished"
```

The variable `$!` will hold the process ID of the last process started in the background.

The `kill -0` will not send a signal to the process, it only make `kill` return with a zero exit status if the given process ID exists and belongs to the user executing `kill`.

One could come up with a solution using `pgrep` too, but that will probably be a bit more "unsafe" in the sense that care must be taken not to catch any similar running processes.

Comment: I have found `kill -0` to exhibit seldom strange side-effects. Better to check if `/proc/$pid` is a directory. Good answer nonetheless.

Comment: @LinusKleen Please explain. Also, relying on `/proc` existing will make a script inherently non-portable.